# Reader-process termination on FIFO-file closing

Tags: c, glibc, mkfifo

I've written a simple reader-writer pair of programs. Writer creates/opens a FIFO-file and is constantly writing a string into it. The reader is just reading it and writing to stdout. The reader does so only for 10 times and then quits. Surprisingly (for me) the writer almost immediately exits too. It does not just go out of writing loop, it seems to jump out of it, I can tell it by not seeing the final "byebye" on the screen. I could sort of accept such behaviour, but I still can't understand why.
Could someone please kindly share their knowledge with me?

```
/* writer code */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char msg [] = "Leo_Tolstoy";

    size_t len = strlen("Leo_Tolstoy");

    if (mkfifo ("myfifo", 0600) != 0) {
        perror ("creating fifo");
    }
    int fd;
    if ( (fd = open ("myfifo", O_WRONLY)) == -1) {
        perror ("opening fifo");
        exit (1);
    }
    while (1)
    {
        int r = write (fd, msg, len);
        if (r == -1)
            perror ("writing");
        sleep(1);
    }
    printf ("byebye\n");
    close (fd);
    return 0;
}
/* reader code */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[50];

    printf ("bef opening\n");
    int fd = open ("myfifo", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror ("opening fifo");
        exit (1);
    }

    printf ("bef reading\n");
    int cnt=0;
    while (cnt < 10)
    {
        int r = read (fd, buf, 50);
        if (r == 0)
            break;
        if (r == -1)
            perror ("reading");
        write (1, buf, r);
        cnt++;
    }
//  close (fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, C or C++. I would say C, but that's your call. Please choose *one* language, not 2 (your question doesn't seem to apply to different languages).

Comment: There is no language C/C++, but the two **different** languages C and C++. Pick **one** of them.

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: I chose C). I didn't use debugger, it's a shame but I don't know how to use gdb and I don't have an IDE installed right now (it's just a VM with Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: `if (mkfifo ("myfifo", 0600) != 0)` is using an octal value, 384 decimal, if that is relevant.

Comment: I sincerely admit that don't know what exactly 0600 means but it's supposed to work since everybody I read use that value. And yes I know it's an octal value.

Comment: You yourself don't understand the code _you_ wrote?

Comment: @daniel.kish `man 2 umask`. should fill you in on the relevance of that value.

Comment: That while loop in the reader looks like it would be better as a for loop. That doesn't help your problem, but it makes the code more clear.

Comment: regarding `0600`  this is the permissions for the fifo node.  it says `octal`, `owner=read/write`, `group=no permissions`, `world=no permissions`

Comment: in the writer code, this line: `int r = write (fd, msg, len);` is not quite correct.  the function: `write()` returns a `ssize_t`, not an `int`

Comment: when the call to `mkfifo()` fails, there is no reason to continue with the code execution after outputting the error message, so the call to `perror()` should be followed by a call to `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: the call to `mkfifo()` will fail, with error code `EEXIST` when the fifo already exists.  Strongly suggest 1) check for failure 2) delete the fifo file after all communication is completed

Comment: the reader code is missing the statement: `#include <unistd.h>`, so the functions: `read()` and `write()` are not defined

Comment: when this line evaluates to 'true' `if (r == -1)`, then is followed by all call to `perror()`, it needs a following statement: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: a fifo has no concept of records, it is just a stream of bytes, so the code needs to implement a check that a full record was read, and if not, try to read the rest of the record.    And the code needs to call `close(fd);` when done reading the fifo

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, 1) use meaningful variable names.  `r` is NOT a meaningful variable name.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`   I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: the code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  in this case, 10 and 50.   Strongly suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: in modern C, when the `main()` function has no 'return 0;` statement at the end, the compiler will automatically cause a return of 0, so no longer necessary to have the `return 0;` statement at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the exits (after 10 iterations), the writer receives a `SIGPIPE` due to the read end being closed. So, the default action for the signal `SIGPIPE` is executed which to terminate the program. That's why you don't see the final printf() is not executed.

Instead you could ignore (`SIG_IGN`) the signal `SIGPIPE` in the writer by calling `sigaction()` and then handle the write error yourself.

Comment: Alright, now i've specified a signal handler for SIGPIPE and everything seems to work. Thanks.